# encoding most efficient way 64 character sequence for lesser writing time to memory

Tags: performance, encoding

The problem is as follows: Given a 64 charater sequences which is built from the english alphabet having 26 charcaters therefore just case characters, the occurrence distribution is such that any character has an equal chance of occurring at a given time.

Due to the fact that I have some computation which needs to be done with regards to the sequences, which requires writing to a text files, since the amount of sequences goes beyond a given ram. I thought of encoding a sequence such that I would be able to have lesser amount of bytes to write to a text file per given sequence.

With such reasoning I thought of the L-Z which would allow me to go down to 40 bytes. Is there any way by which i can go lower to encode a 64 character sequence?

Comment: I took the liberty of an edit to define the distribution in more conventional mathematical terms. But you ought to consider submitting sample code or this could get closed quite quickly. And add a language tag if you can.

Comment: Theoretically, you should be able to use log2(26) (approximately 4.7) bits per character bringing it down to 37.6 bytes.

Comment: If you know the input is constrained to 26 possibilities, you can use 5 bytes (32 possibilities) to encode a character. This comes down to 40 bytes for 64 characters, uncompressed.

This way you'd be limiting the compression possibilities though, because AFAIK most compression algorithms operate on entire bytes of 8 bits.

Comment: No Im open to other compression algorithms, I just mentioned my train of thought

Comment: Other than 5 bits / per character improvement mentioned, it is not possible to compress random data. http://gailly.net/05533051.html

Comment: Huffman coding lets you go lower on "typical" text.  This all makes extremely little sense today.

Comment: lower than 40 bytes will become MUCH more complicated for only 2 bytes (5%) of gain. Of course it's none of my business, but you might reconsider it ^^

Answer (score 0):

With a large(-ish) lookup table you could encode each of the possible `26^64` character sequences in `301` (actually `300.8281==log2(26^64)`) bits.  This is slightly less than the `320` bits your straightforward compression would use. It is also the theoretical minimum given that any of the 26 characters occurs with equal probability.

Since you could derive the lookup table at any time you don't even need to store it.  I suppose the bits used to represent the functions to encode a character string into a `301`-bit integer and *vice-versa* ought to be counted into your compression ratio.

This is, of course, a long-winded restatement of @lhf's comment.

Comment: Do you need a look up table? Can't you generate the sequence from 301 bit pattern immediately?

Comment: I believe that the second paragraph of my answer touches on the need to store a lookup table.

Comment: No. If you believe that you can, post an answer explaining how.

Comment: I didn't try it but always under impression that it should be possible - http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0201853930/thealgorithmrepo :)